# Compose Landscape BoxWithConstraints has wrong height. (aspectRatio matchHeightConstraintsFirst not working as expected)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've got a view that I want to be in a 16x9 ratio.

In portrait it looks fine:

[image]

In landscape it is using an incorrect height, and so the text is not centered:

[image]

(You can scroll to the see the rest of the view:

[image])

The code to reproduce is:

```
/**
 * Portrait: width=375.6dp height=211.4dp
 * Landscape: expecting height=375.6dp but get height=443.1dp (a height that is taller than the screen is wide, not constrained?)
 */
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            RotationHeightDemoTheme {
//                Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) { // swapping out LazyColumn to Column with verticalScroll still gives the same issue
                LazyColumn {
                    item {
                        BoxWithConstraints(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .aspectRatio(16f / 9f, matchHeightConstraintsFirst = true)
                                // .fillParentMaxSize() // Using this "fixes" the issue in landscape but breaks portrait
                                .background(Color.Red),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "BOX $maxWidth / $maxHeight")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Commenting in `.fillParentMaxSize` 'fixes' landscape:

[image]

but breaks portrait:

[image]

I need to keep the LazyColumn because in portrait other views could be on the screen which will be invisible in landscape.

Why in landscape does the BoxWithConstraints have the wrong height dimension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that inside the Column's content lambda, the constraints that are received by the items have an infinite height value, since the content is allowed to scroll vertically as much as it would like to.

You can get the real size of your container and store it somewhere.
Then you can use this value to pass into your component's max width/size constraints so that it never goes above those limits. After that you can apply the aspectRation modifier.
In code:

```kotlin
var layoutSize: IntSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize(0, 0)) }
Column(
  modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxSize() // Ensure that your container takes up all the space it can so that we get the right size value here
      .onSizeChanged { intSize -> // *Very* important that this happens before `verticalScroll` is applied
          layoutSize = intSize // Store the real value before the vertical contraints go infinite when we make it scrollable
      }
      .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
) {
  val density = LocalDensity.current
  BoxWithConstraints(
    modifier = Modifier
      .sizeIn(maxWidth = with(density) { layoutSize.width.toDp() }, maxHeight = with(density) { layoutSize.height.toDp() })
      .aspectRatio(16f / 9f, matchHeightConstraintsFirst = true)
      .background(Color.Red),
  ) {
    Text(text = "BOX $maxWidth / $maxHeight")
  }
}
```

This will give the child item the right max constraints, and then everything is smooth sailing after that, any modifier under it will operate under the right max constraints, aspectRatio included in your case.

One thing to care about here is that on the first frame the `layoutSize` will have the default size of `0,0` or whatever you have inside the `mutableStateOf`. So that may look a bit jarring, depending on your scenario. But you can do something like not show the content yet when the layoutSize is in the default case